# Need to Post Text in Twitter using ASP.Net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, twitter

I want to post on Twitter timeline using Asp.Net web page.
I have registered my page in twitter developer account and got all keys and tokens.
I have tried with code from 
[Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/114478/Twitter-Made-Easy-Post-to-Your-Twitter-Account-wit),
[DotNet Tutorial](http://www.dotnettutorials.com/tutorials/advanced/asp-twitter-posting/),
 DotNet Funda
www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/3196/post-message-with-image-on-twitter-using-csharp

Web page is running good but nothing is posted to twitter account.
Please provide me some working link where I will get some hints or find the code.

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to Tweetsharp, [Tweetinvi](https://github.com/linvi/tweetinvi) is being actively being developed.
With this library you can actually post a tweet

```
// Setup the credentials of the account to use
Auth.SetUserCredentials("CONSUMER_KEY", "CONSUMER_SECRET", "ACCESS_TOKEN", "ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET");

// Upload the image/video that you want to attach to your Tweet (up to 4 images)
byte[] binary = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
var media = Upload.UploadImage(binary);

// Publish your tweet
var tweet = Tweet.PublishTweet("This is my awesome photo!", new PublishTweetOptionalParameters
{
    Medias = new List<IMedia> { media }
});

// The variable tweet now contains all the information provided by Twitter.
```

You can find more information about how to publish a Tweet in the documentation : https://github.com/linvi/tweetinvi/wiki/Tweets.

Tweetinvi github project provide an example project (Examplinvi.Web) that does exactly what you are looking for.

You can find it here :

- [Controller](https://github.com/linvi/tweetinvi/blob/master/Examplinvi.Web/Controllers/TweetController.cs)
- [View](https://github.com/linvi/tweetinvi/blob/master/Examplinvi.Web/Views/Tweet/Index.cshtml)
- [Success Publish View](https://github.com/linvi/tweetinvi/blob/master/Examplinvi.Web/Views/Tweet/TweetPublished.cshtml)

Please let me know if this answers your question. Also note that I am the main developer of the library.

Comment: I have tried this but Tweet.PublishTweet is not working.No error ,exceptions are coming only clicking button returns nothing.  I have got some other way out.Using this link ""http://www.twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=" + TextBox1.Text" I have meet my requirement